# breeze.js originalValuesMap Error

Tags: javascript, dictionary, breeze, parent

I'm getting a random error when deleting a child entity in a parent/child relationship.  I have a "call" entity (parent) and a "callAction" (child).  There are occasions where deleting the child results in a server error :

```
Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Int64.
```

I have pinpointed it down to the JSON payload being sent to the server.  When the error occurs, the callAction entity has data in the originalValuesMap.  It has 1 entry, and that is the FK property to the parent.

When the error does NOT occur, the originalValuesMap is empty.  Two questions:

1) What could be causing originalValuesMap to sometimes have data, and sometimes not? I am not updating any of the parent properties.  I am just deleting (setDeleted) the child.

2) Since it's a delete, shouldn't these other properties be ignored?  It's a single delete transaction, there are no other entitites in the payload.

Comment: thanks for re-formating.

Comment: Jay, do you have any idea on this one?  Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: I can't repro this. So if you can repro it with a new unit test in the DocCode sample, and post the test here, I'll take a look.

Comment: can you shed some light on the originalValuesMap object and under what conditions it comes into play?  Since my issue happens randomly I can't  repro it, there's something else in my code that is at fault.  If I knew some of the conditions the map gets populated that would give me a start.  thanks